# Why these associations between DC characters and the Seven Deadly Sins?

Tags: dc, religion

I'm not much a DC fan as a Batman fan, so the less a character is related to Batman the less I know about them.

I can't remember exactly from which series this picture is. It shows the 7 statues that represent the Seven Deadly Sins of Man in the Rock of Eternity (the base of operations of the wizard Shazam).

[image: jlajsa7deadlysins.jpg]

This time, instead of mockingly cartoon-like stone statues the statues have the shape or resemblance of DC characters.The association of Batman with *Anger* is obvious. I get the association between Plastic Man and *Greed* too (IIRC he was a thief before acquiring his powers). Probably *Lust* has to do more with the attire of Power Girl than with the character herself.

I don't know enough of the characters to understand why they were chosen to represent Pride, Envy or Gluttony (well, for this latter one, maybe it has to do more with Billy Batson than with Captain Marvel himself). The association of Dr. Fate with *Sloth* is especially surprising to me. I don't know much about this character either, but it never stroke to me like lazy or apathetic.

By the way, it is impossible to read in the image, but Zatanna there says that these images of the *Seven Deadly Enemies of Man* resembling their teammates are representations of **"their inner spirits and souls"**.

Could somebody explain why this DC characters have been chosen to represent each Deadly Sin?

Comment: Which Green Lantern is it? Because IIRC, Guy Gardner is traditionally jealous of other Green Lanterns and superheroes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How are these members of the Justice League and the Justice Society related to the Seven Deadly Sins below them? Most of these relationships have less to do with the character and more to do with the person beneath the costume.

In almost every case, the issue is related to some aspect of their lives before they became superhuman or began working in their respective metahuman communities. Starting from the far left:

**Mr. Terrific is associated with Pride:** The lead technologist of the Justice Society, Mr. Terrific's personal sin is Pride. He is very proud of his great intellect, his technological expertise and his inventions he has created.

[image]

His technology is diverse, powerful and still subtle and unobtrusive. His pride however, challenges his good sense, especially when he is compared to other intellects in the DC Universe.

He is most commonly called the Third Smartest Man in the World, with Lex Luthor being listed as number one, and number two is never officially named… Grr. I can relate to his perspective given the number of super-geniuses littering the DC Universe.

**Green Lantern, Kyle Rayner is associated with Envy:** Kyle Rayner, Green Lantern, later Ion, is associated with the sin of Envy. Kyle was at one point in the DC Universe, the only Green Lantern in the Universe.

[image]

Even with that being the case, he was constantly compared to, at this point, legendary superhero, emotional basket case, and Green Lantern Corps murderer, Hal Jordan, who was regularly called one of the greatest Green Lanterns to have ever lived, despite, in my personal opinion having some of the worst behavior a space policeman/interstellar diplomat/Green Lantern Corps Representative could possibly have.

[image]

Nevertheless, Kyle was often bombarded with tales of Hal Jordan’s success, even as Kyle was doing incredible things during his tenure as a member of the GLC. Kyle would eventually get over his envy of Hal Jordan and become an amazing member of the Corps in his own right, becoming one of the few beings to ever wield more than one ring simultaneously and eventually becoming the legendary White Lantern.

**Plastic Man is associated with Greed:** "Eel" Obrien was a career criminal, complete with gang and hideout. During a failed robbery, Eel is doused in strange chemicals which change him making him able to alter his shape and become like rubber. An act of kindness forced him to consider his criminal lifestyle and convinced him to change is ways.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Eel would use his criminal background to fight crime until his eventual induction into the Justice League, his personal relationship with money never truly improved and for a time, he struggled with maintaining his status as a law-abiding citizen.

To his credit Plas remained on the straight and narrow despite his temptation but this indicates perhaps he doesn’t have his compulsion completely under control…

**Batman is associated with Anger:** Batman’s alter ego, Bruce Wayne is cultured, civilized, urbane and a complete construct created by the controlled rage in Human form that is The Batman. His near-boundless rage in his war against crime is a pathological struggle in his attempt to reconcile his helplessness during the murder of his parents in that dark alley all those years ago. No matter how many lives he saves, no matter how many villains he stops, the only cure for him is to constantly seek out danger and vent his spleen upon it. There may be other sins Batman could be associated with but Anger is definitely at the top of his list.

[image]

**Dr. Fate is associated with Sloth:** Doctor Fate, one of the core members of the Justice Society was associated with Sloth. It too me a minute to make the connection and I admit I may not be completely on the mark.

[image]

Doctor Fate is a complex character and extremely powerful character; his powers come from his relationship with the Lord of Fate, Nabu, trapped within his helmet. Left to his own devices, Nabu would meddle constantly in the affairs of men, in order to balance the Universe between the forces of Order and Chaos.

[image]

His longest running host was Kent Nelson, who often does not agree with Nabu’s decisions and tries to temper the entity’s desire to rewrite the world in his image. Kent Nelson (at many times in his depiction) is an older man who might like to rest from his particular stewardship but is afraid Nabu would have undue control over his next host and thus while wanting to put the Helm of Nabu down, feared ever letting it fall into the wrong hands. For Kent, his sin would be his desire for Sloth, to take time away from his never-ending struggle with his duty. Nabu on the other hand is always ready to absorb another host willing or not...

[image]

**Power Girl is associated with Lust:** While Power Girl’s is associated with Lust, it is not particularly a sin associated FROM her, but instead TOWARD her. Power Girl has spent a good portion of her superheroic career having to push away the advances of every relatively healthy male libido that has ever come across her path. A liberated woman, she take guff from no man and has the power to back it up. This makes her choice in costumes (from the character perspective) a sign of her sexual independence, displaying her “assets” without fear of physical or cultural reprisal. (For the record, I HATE her costume because it is definitely part of a sexual issue with female characters, male writers and male fans that has existed as long as comics have.) Sigh.

[image]

**Captain Marvel (Billy Batson) is associated with Gluttony:** Billy Batson is associated with Gluttony because Billy is an orphan, for a time was living in less than ideal quarters in social services and has been portrayed as, at least until he is adopted, living on the edge of complete and utter poverty. His identity as Captain Marvel is both wish fulfillment and escapism from the nature of his living arrangements. Captain Marvel, who has the wisdom of Solomon would be beyond the blandishments of Gluttony as a sin but the all too Human, Billy knows all to well what extreme hunger feels like and the shadow of Gluttony would lay across his soul.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is that last bit from? I'd love to read it!

Comment: Superman/Shazam: First Thunder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Shazam:_First_Thunder

Comment: Wait a minute, I read that. How did I forget it?

Comment: Old age comes for us all, @Broklynite.

Comment: Damn whippersnappers- get off my lawn @ThaddeusHowze!

Comment: It's not that Power Girl suffers from lust or gives into it, and it's not that she's actively trying to seduce anyone. I think it's that she specifically chooses a costume that turns men on -- deliberately inspiring lust. She usually refuses their advances instead of luring men to her bed, but she *could* simply dress more modestly.